# Is there a data structure like a map but will maintain the transitive property?

Tags: data-structures

For example, if I add two entries to the map: (2->1), and (1->3), the map will then contain: (2->3) and (1->3).

I won't need to remove anything, and I'm only interested in iterating over all the entries after I've added all the mappings I care about.

Comment: Can you remove links, or just add them? Also, are you interested in doing individual point queries (asking "is there a link from X to Y?") or bulk queries ("give me all the links")?

Comment: I don't know of such a thing in any standard language library, but it wouldn't be terribly difficult to build. You'll have to think through all the possibilities, though, like what happens if the items are inserted in the other order: (1->3) and then (2->1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a reachability index, as is used in graph databases. Your numbers become 'nodes', and entries in your map are the 'edges'. Transitivity then becomes reachability in the graph.

One such index is [GRAIL](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~zaki/PaperDir/VLDB10.pdf), the document also compares a list of related approaches.

I have no idea though what is used in practice. If your dataset is small you could just do a brute force approach:

Let's say you add (1->2), then look up all entries with (2->x) and add entries (1->x) for each one. No recursion is necessary, because (2->x) should already be a transitive set.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds a lot like [union-find](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/15uf/).

> Dynamic connectivity. The input is a sequence of pairs of integers, where each integer represents an object of some type and we are to interpret the pair p q as meaning p is connected to q. We assume that "is connected to" is an equivalence relation:
>   *symmetric*: If p is connected to q, then q is connected to p.
>   **transitive**: If p is connected to q and q is connected to r, then p is connected to r.
>   *reflexive*: p is connected to p.